# How can the spacing between widgets in a QGridLayout remain fixed on window resize?

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, pyqt, pyqt4

I am building an application in `PyQT4`. A principle part of this app will be to maintain a grid of widgets (sub classed from `QLineEdit` widgets). I am organizing the widgets into a `QGridLayout`.

When I run the window, I get a grid organized just how I want, i.e.

[image: Grid (initial size)]

However, the `QGridLayout` has the property that it automatically pads the spacing between widgets when the window is resized, i.e.

[image: Grid (expanded size)]

I would love for the grid to have the same spacing between widgets, no matter how I resize the window. I have looked and cannot seem to find how to accomplish this. I would have imagined something that fixes the spacing, but none of the likely sounding functions have this effect.

Here is a code snippet below, specifically just the part with the `QGridLayout`.

```py
class GridBlockTxtbx(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, blocks=5, spaces=5):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dctn_txtbx = {}
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.spaces = spaces

        # Create layout
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        # Set initial spacing between widgets to 2 pixels...
        # I want this to be fixed on window resize!
        layout.setSpacing(2)
        # Function to load the widgets into the grid
        GridBlockTxtbx._gen_block_txtbx_grid(layout, self.blocks,     
                                             self.spaces,
                                             self.dctn_txtbx)
        # Set the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _gen_block_txtbx_grid(layout, rows, cols, dctn):
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                blk = GridBlockTxtbx._gen_block_txtbx(idx=(i, j))
                layout.addWidget(blk, i, j)
                dctn[i, j] = blk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an expanding spacer to the last row/column of the grid-layout:

PyQt5/6:

```
vspacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
    QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
layout.addItem(vspacer, last_row, 0, 1, -1)

hspacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
    QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
layout.addItem(hspacer, 0, last_column, -1, 1)
```

PyQt4:

```
vspacer = QtGui.QSpacerItem(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
layout.addItem(vspacer, last_row, 0, 1, -1)

hspacer = QtGui.QSpacerItem(
    QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
layout.addItem(hspacer, 0, last_column, -1, 1)
```